# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 with Facebook and Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0

I keep getting these errors as I try to build my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAccessToken", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MESignInViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in MEFacebookLoginManager.o
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKGraphRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MEFacebookLoginManager.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginButton", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKLoginManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in MEFacebookLoginManager.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've installed the Facebook and Parse SDK via cocoapods, here's what my Podfile looks like:

```
target 'Ment' do
 pod 'Parse'
 pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
end

target 'MentTests' do

end
```

Any idea what's wrong, this is really bugging me

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to add the facebook pods as well if you're using the facebook login.

```
# facebook
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

and optionally

```
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

To get everything running smoothly, make sure you've followed the [instructions parse have for integrating with facebook](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-setup).